# C# Авторизоваться на сайте через аякс

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте через post запрос

```
string reqString = "http://ДОМЕН/panel/login&login=" + login.Text + "&pass=" + pass.Text;
var client = WebRequest.Create(reqString);
client.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=");
client.Headers["Authorization"] = "YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=";
client.Headers.Add(String.Format("X-Requested-With:{0}", "XMLHttpRequest"));
client.Method = "POST";
client.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencodedn";

HttpWebResponse resp;
using (resp = (HttpWebResponse)client.GetResponse())
{
    if (resp.GetResponseStream() != null)
    {
        var status = resp.StatusDescription;
        var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        var obj = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Авторизация проходит через аякс, пост запросом, как сохранить полученные куки? И составить условие типа: ЕСЛИ авторизация = ПРАВДА - то вывести то то...    ?

Comment: Или как вообще я могу авторизироваться через приложение у себя на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

```
private async Task<string> Authorize(string userName, string passwd)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://ДОМЕН/panel/login");

        // Тело запроса
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", userName),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pass", password)
        });

        var client = new HttpClient();

        // Добавляешь нужные тебе заголовки, для примера взял Accept-type
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), formContent);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic jsonResult = JObject.Parse(responseContent);

        // Тут уже зависит от структуры ответа на запрос. 
        // Для примера достаешь status из запроса.

        return jsonResult.status;
    }

public async Task<ActionResult> LoginInExternal()
{
    var response= await Authorize("login@login.ru", "password");
    response == 1 ? Console.WriteLine("Авторизован") : Console.WriteLine("Не Авторизован");
}
```

Если запрос не идёт, можешь потестить с помощью какой-либо утилиты по типу Postman.
На Windows устанавливается через расширения Chrome, для Mac, насколько я помню, из AppStore.

Comment: Проверю, отпишусь, благодарю !

Comment: @Елизавета Ты ещё уточни в какой формате тебе ответ приходит.
JSON или XML?

Comment: Моя студия половину кода заменила, по итогу все равно не хочет работать (

Comment: @Елизавета Что значит "половину кода заменила"?
Ошибка при компиляции или просто запрос не проходит?

Comment: ошибка компиляции, httpclient и другие классы ... переделываю методы